# Make system calls (Windows Command Prompt) answer in english

Tags: windows, localization, command-prompt

I'm working on a Perl script that needs to do a few system calls to obtain some system data. In order to parse the output of those calls reliably on any computer, I need to be sure the output of the call is set to English.

The problem I'm facing is that, for example in my PC, I get localized output from those commands. My Windows is setup in Spanish so, calls like `systeminfo` return data in Spanish.

Is there a command (or something else) I can run in a command call to make all system calls act like if the system was in English always, without having to modify anything in the system configuration?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

NOTES for bounty: The answer to this problem must not interfere with the system in any way. It should be a way to obtain english answers from system calls/commands that works in any machine without modifying its configuration, registry or else.

Comment: This is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](http://wandersick.blogspot.com/p/change-non-english-command-line.html) allows you to make Command Prompt act in english. It does alter some registry keys but it also changes them back if you want. You can run the same commands that they put in the `.bat`s to make the system go to english and them go back to localized.

If you're trying to run commands that require adminsitrator privileges, then you can include these calls in your program without problems.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I think the [WMIC](http://ss64.com/nt/wmicglobal.html) command is your best best. It has been a standard feature of Windows since Windows XP.

WMIC has *full* access to the Windows system (subject to user permissions, etc.), and has a locale option that selects the locale in effect (for the command) from the installed language packs.

The locale is selected from the list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/goglobal/bb964664.aspx).

To get the current username using US English (if it's available) you'd use `wmic /locale:ms_409 netlogin get name`

Through the WMI interface, you may not even need to localise the results (i.e.: with sufficient care, you may just get the raw data).

Comment: Thank you, but WMIC is very limiting to certain info. I mentioned some examples of commands I need to run but those are not all the commands I need.